# how to prevent a event listener function to be triggered several times at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, discord, discord.js

my question is easy I'm using discord js and have this event listener in my code.
this listener function is triggered when a user sends a particular message in a channel. But if 2 users send this particular message at the same time the listener function is triggered twice at the same time. How can I prevent this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are happy to ignore the second message coming through you could have a look at wrapping your function with [debouncing](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/debounce-in-javascript-improve-your-applications-performance-5b01855e086), which would cause it to only trigger once if called in short succession.

[Lodash has a package for this that can be imported individually](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce)

```
import { myFunc } from 'somewhere';
import { debounce } from 'somewhereElse';

const DEBOUNCE_DELAY_MS = 500;
const myDebouncedFunc = debounce(myFunc, DEBOUNCE_DELAY_MS);

// Call myDebouncedFunc twice immediately after each other, the 
// debouncing will result in the function only getting called max once 
// every 500ms;
myDebouncedFunc();
myDebouncedFunc();
```

Otherwise, if you need to have both messages processed, just not at the same time, then you would need something like a queue for processing these events. Then you could process these messages in an interval for example.

```
// Some lexically available scope
const myQueue = [];

// Event handler
const myHandler = (msg) => {
  myQueue.push(msg);
}

// Interval processing
setInterval(() => {
  if (myQueue.length > 0) {
    const msgToProcess = myQueue.shift();
    processMessage(msgToProcess);
  }
}, 500)
```

Comment: Thanks ! But shouldn't it be myQueue.length > 0 ?

Comment: @andrc Yes you are right. I'll edit it now. If you are happy with this answer please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions to this problem depending on your needs.

1. Unregister the event listener as soon as the even comes. In most libraries, you can easily achieve by registering your event using [once()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#once) method, instead of "on()"
2. Use [debounce()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce) to aggregate all the events triggered within a certain amount of time into one.

The same or similar methods exist in most of JS libraries similar to lodash.